# How to set resolution to native screen resolution? (over 1920x1080)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

I have a 17" laptop with Intel 6700HQ and Nvidia 950M inside (ASUS N752VX).

When I boot Windows, it starts with native resolution of the display which is 2560x1440. On Ubuntu, I can't go over 1920x1080.

My nvidia settings are like this

[image]

I can't change the Virtual Size from here and I don't see any line to change on xorg.conf.

These are my display settings

[image]

The resolution drop down menu doesn't go above 1080p.

Comment: If you open a terminal and enter `xrandr`, what is the output please?

Comment: Tried pasting here but [this'll work better guess.](http://imgur.com/a/rpFo1)